# How to publish only(!) parts of an Excel-Document on a SharePoint 2013 server?

Tags: 2013, excel

We have an Excel document which contains in 2 columns information about a product (column A) and its delivery time (column B).
In column C, there are also internal comments about the reasons for this delivery time.

The Excel-document is stored on a normal Windows file server.
It is **updated daily** and those changes shall be reflected also immediately on SharePoint:

We want to publish the information from columns A and B (and NOT the info from Column C) on a SharePoint 2013 server (Standard), maybe in another Excel document, but it could also be in a list or on a webpage.

Which ways are there to make that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure **excel services**, to display excel file from SharePoint site or network shared path or from web folder address.

**Refer this link to configure excel services:**
[How to Configure Excel Services in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-configure-excel-services-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Now to show only column A and B from that excel, you will need to **Defined Name items** in workbook.

> A named item can be a chart, table, a PivotChart report, a PivotTable
>   report, a slicer, a Timeline control, a worksheet, or even a range of
>   data in a worksheet.

**Reference for Named Item:** [Share workbooks by using Excel Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/share-workbooks-by-using-excel-services-sharepoint-server-2013)

Comment: Thank you! According to the first link you posted, 'Excel Services' requires SharePoint 2013 **Enterprise**, we are currently using Standard. :-(

Comment: Hi mBBe, another option you can try is to embed excel on SharePoint page. Below are some links.

Comment: http://3sharp.com/blog/embedding-excel-files-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-it-Embed-an-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-OneDrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-your-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-SharePoint-or-OneDrive-for-Business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

Hide column C in the workbook and protect the sheet, so the hidden column cannot be unhidden by the regular user.

Or don't use an Excel spreadsheet in the first place. Use a SharePoint list instead and create the default view with only column A and B. Use permissions to determine who can see a view with column C for updating the list.

Comment: thank you very muc h! I did not know that I can use permissions for views. Is this possible in SharePoint 2013 Standard? But can I then be sure that a user does not create his own view which shows the "secret" column C?

Comment: You can't- at least not directly in a list view. But you can set up a Page with a list view Web part that shows columns A, B and C. Then you can restrict who can access that page with permissions. And you can use list permissions to ensure that users cannot build their own views.

Comment: thanks a lot! This looks like our solution, as the Excel Services need SharePoint Enterprise, which we do not have.

Comment: is there a way to update the Sharepoint List automatically from the original Excel file, each time the file is saved?

Comment: No. You keep the data in SharePoint, you edit the data in SharePoint. You can read SharePoint data into Excel, but you cannot write Excel data into Sharepoint. Sorry. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Thanks again - it was not my intention to shoot anyone. ;-) I thought I had read somewhere that it is possible to create a one way or bidirectional data connection between a SharePoint List and an Excel file, but I assume this are the 'Excel Services' which I can not use in SP Standard.